# SQL Prevent Duplicate Entry

Tags: php, sql, duplicates

Users send sql queries and sometimes (usually server busy) sql lines duplicated. I want prevent it. Example if user send same query at the same time, sql accept only one query. I dont want delete it always.. Can i do it on phpmyadmin?

If i cant, problem in this php:
http://www.speedyshare.com/S4QRj/Automation.php

I think in this code:

```
    private function returnunitsComplete() {
    global $database;
    $time = time();
    $q = "SELECT * FROM ".TB_PREFIX."movement, ".TB_PREFIX."attacks where ".TB_PREFIX."movement.ref = ".TB_PREFIX."attacks.id and ".TB_PREFIX."movement.proc = '0' and ".TB_PREFIX."movement.sort_type = '4' and endtime < $time";
    $dataarray = $database->query_return($q);


    foreach($dataarray as $data) {

    $tribe = $database->getUserField($database->getVillageField($data['to'],"owner"),"tribe",0);

    if($tribe == 1){ $u = ""; } elseif($tribe == 2){ $u = "1"; } elseif($tribe == 3){ $u = "2"; } elseif($tribe == 4){ $u = "3"; } else{ $u = "4"; }
    $database->modifyUnit(
            $data['to'],
            array($u."1",$u."2",$u."3",$u."4",$u."5",$u."6",$u."7",$u."8",$u."9",$tribe."0","hero"),
            array($data['t1'],$data['t2'],$data['t3'],$data['t4'],$data['t5'],$data['t6'],$data['t7'],$data['t8'],$data['t9'],$data['t10'],$data['t11']),
            array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
    );
    $database->setMovementProc($data['moveid']);
    }
```

Sometimes return units and reports duplicated. Sorry for my bad English. Thank you...

Comment: Have you looked into `UNIQUE` column indexes?

Comment: When you say queries mean question to database or data to insert in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Use `CONSTRAINT` in your table like `PRIMARY KEY` and/or `UNIQUE KEY` . They won't accept same value.

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)  //primary key
)
```

For more, refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: Can you explain it? How can i do?

Comment: you need to define it, in your table structure.

Comment: @user1936293 please accept the answer, if your problem resolved,

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure the pair of columns `col1` and `col2` of the table `tbl1` doesn't contain duplicate pairs of values (but each column by itself can), you can create the neccessary unique index as

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1
  ADD UNIQUE KEY(col1, col2)
```

Documentation (MySQL): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: The syntax is `ALTER TABLE ... **ADD** UNIQUE KEY ...`